# can I revert the changes on a remote repository that I pushed to?

Tags: git, github

my teammate created a remote repo and she pushed to it some files x y and z.
I was working on same files, but without sync with the remote repo so she asked me to push my changes on top of her changes.
Initially the remote repo had 2 commits done by my teammate.
What I did is, on my pc the folder where I am editing files x y and z, I ran the follow:

```
git init
git remote add origin {remote repo clone link}
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit by me"
git push --setupstream origin master it was rejected with error message:

fatal: helper error (-1): Cannot access a disposed object.
To ********************************
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to '***************************'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I ran the command again with -f to force, and suddenly I see my changes with only 1 commit which is mine :( .
Can I revert this on the remote branch?!

Comment: Sounds like the remote commits used to be on the master branch, then the master branch was reset -f to some other commit. So now the remote commits are no longer referenced on any branch. If that is the case, it does not sound possible, unless somehow you have access to the remote file system / disk and can run commands there such as `git log --reflog` which would show all commits, allowing you to reset -f anywhere. Alternatively, try to clone the remote repo again in a different location and look for forgotten branches (if there are any) and maybe recover some commits (but it's a long shot).

Comment: Just do what the error message tells you: `fetch` the history from the remote repo. Then `rebase` your *local* master branch  onto the *remote* master branch.

Comment: Maybe let your teammate force push back his original stuff you overwrote? And then take a vow never to force push to a shared remote ever again.

Comment: Incidentally, `fatal: helper error (-1): Cannot access a disposed object.` indicates a bug in some `.net` credential helper (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29626/1256452) for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You don't push *files*, in Git.  Git isn't about files.  Git is about *commits*—so you push *commits*.  So when you say:

> my teammate created a remote repo and she pushed to it some files x y and z.

What you mean is *she pushed some commits; those commits contained files* (as all commits do).

The thing—well, *a* thing—about commits in Git is this:

- *Git* finds them by raw hash IDs.
- *Humans*, however, are bad at raw hash IDs.  They're really big and ugly and random-looking, e.g., `30cc8d0f147546d4dd77bf497f4dec51e7265bd8` (an actual commit in the Git repository for Git).  No human can remember them reliably.  But they're also *unique:* once one of these IDs has been used up, no other Git anywhere, ever, can use that same ID for anything else.  (That's why they're so big and ugly.)
- Because we can't handle the hash IDs, Git provides *branch names* for us.
- A *branch name* contains *exactly one hash ID*.

The hash ID stored *in* a branch name is, by definition, the *latest* commit.  Whatever hash ID is in that branch name, that's the latest commit.

The other thing—well, *an*-other thing—about commits in Git is this: each commit stores the hash ID(s) of some earlier commit(s), as a list of *parents*.  Most commits contain exactly one parent hash ID.  So this means that commits form a backwards-looking chain.

Suppose the *last* commit on some branch has some hash ID.  I won't even try to guess what it is, or write it down; instead, I'll just call it `H` for "hash".  Since it's the *last* commit on some branch, it's the hash ID stored *in the branch name*.  We say that the name *points to* this commit.

This commit itself stores a list—one element long—of *previous* commit hash IDs, so we say that this commit *points to* the previous commit.  Let's draw commit `H`, with a branch name pointing to it:

```
            <-H   <--branch
```

Now, the earlier commit that `H` points to: let's call it `G` and draw it in:

```
        <-G <-H   <--branch
```

Commit `G` of course points backwards to yet another earlier commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch
```

and this goes on forever, or rather, until we get to the *very first commit ever*.  It stops there because the *first* commit didn't have an earlier commit, so its list of earlier commit hash IDs is empty.

> [I ran]
>
> ```
> git init
> git remote add origin {remote repo clone link}
> git add .
> git commit -m "initial commit by me"
> git push --setupstream origin master
> ```

Your `git init` created a new, totally-empty repository, with no commits and no branches at all.  You then made one initial commit—that very first commit that has no previous commits—which also created the branch name `master`.  So in *your* repository you had this:

```
A   <-- master
```

> [my `git push` was rejected, with error message as quoted ...]

Let's draw the commits in the *other* repository, starting with `B`.  You said there were two, so we'll call them `B` and `C`.  They had:

```
B <-C   <-- master
```

Your Git software sent your commit `A` to them; they put it in their repository (technically in a temporary area).  Then your Git software asked them—politely—to make *their* name `master` point to `A`.  It *could* do that, but if it did so, it would have:

```
A   <-- master

B <-C   ???
```

That is, there would be no *name* by which anyone could *find commit `C`*.

So they said *no, I can't do that, I'll lose some commits if I do that*.

> So I ran the command again with -f to force

The force flag changes your polite request ("If it's OK, make your `master` point to the commit(s) I sent") to a *command* telling them to *do it now dammit*.  They don't have to obey, but in this case, they did.

They (probably) still have commits `B` and `C`!  It's just that you, and they, can't *find* them any more, unless you've memorized the hash IDs.  (Did you?)

As [firmament wrote in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73055360/can-i-revert-the-changes-on-a-remote-repository-that-i-pushed-to#comment129030518_73055360), if your teammate still has *their* repository, they still have their commits.  They can use *their* repository to find the hash ID of their commit `C`.  They can use `git push -f` to send their `B-C` chain to the third (shared) repository, which will actually already still have `B-C` so that will go very fast, and then command that repository to set its `master` to point to `C`, thus "losing" your commit `A`.  That's one option.

Or, if you have some way to *find the hash ID* of commit `C`—for instance, if it's in scrollback in a window on your computer—it's possible that you can *fetch* commits `B` and `C` *from* that third repository, the one you're calling `origin`.  You can try:

```
git fetch origin <raw-hash-ID-of-commit-C>:refs/heads/recovered
```

which is a bit magic, but basically tells your Git software to call up the Git software at `origin`, ask them for commit `C` by hash ID, and if they can send you `C`—which will come with `B` as well because that's how Git rolls: you normally get *all* the commits from the end backwards to the beginning, and then hang on to *all* of them forever, or as long as you can find the hash IDs—they will send you `C`.  Then *your* Git will create a *new branch name* in your repository, `recovered`, to remember `C`'s hash ID.

You can now run `git log recovered` to see commit `C`.  Since `git log` works by starting from the commit you name—the new branch name `recovered` will point to `C`, so that's the commit you name here—and then *works backwards from there*, you'll see commit `B` as well.  (Since `B` is a "very first" commit—you now have two such commits!—the `git log` output will stop there.)

Either way, by having your teammate push, or by using this recovery trick, you can get all three commits (`A`, `B`, and `C`) into your repository.  Then you can make a *new and improved* version of commit `A` that *adds on* to `C`:

```
A   <-- master

B <-C <-D   <-- recovered
```

for instance, where `D` is the new and improved commit.  You then need only swap the two names around:

```
git branch -m master old-master
git branch -m recovered master
```

and you'll have:

```
A   <-- old-master

B <-C <-D   <-- master
```

You can now `git push origin master` (**without** `--force`), which sends your new commit `D` to `origin`—it offers them `C` too, but they already have that—and then asks them, politely, if they can make their name `master` point to `D`.  Since this *adds on*, they *can* this time, and that's the kind of `git push` you probably should have done originally.

(There are other ways to do this, such as merging the two branches, but modern `git merge` doesn't really like to merge "unrelated histories", which these would be.  That's also not the normal way to get things done.)

Comment: Hi Torek, thank you for the detaield explanation!
One thing still confuses me, what does this command do `git remote add origin {remote repo clone link}` ? I though it syncs with remote repo so that when I push my commit, it will be aware of other commits.
Another thing, in my case, initially couldn't I just push my commit before pulling?